# File.Copy Throwing throw "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" error

Tags: c#, .net-core

i am trying to copy a file from staging folder to inbound folder . not sure what i m doing wrong

```
 File.Copy("//o1-app-03/na_dev$/STAGE/RMS.TXT", "//o1-app-03/na_dev$/INBOUND/RMS/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add desired destination file name to the second argument cause [`File.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_) has two parameters, both of them are file names:

```
public static void Copy (string sourceFileName, string destFileName);
```